# Concatenate Two Query Sets - Ruby on Rails with MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, activerecord

I have two different models say CoachTrainingSession and OrganizationTrainingSession which has common field :client_id.

**coach_training_session.rb**

```
class CoachTrainingSession
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :coach

  field :session_id      #firebase ID
  field :date_time, type: DateTime
  field :completed, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :cancelled, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :client_ids, type: Array
  field :group_name

  index({client_id: 1})
  index({session_id: 1})
  index({date_time: 1})
  index({client_ids: 1})
  index({group_name: 1})

  has_many :booked_sessions
end
```

**organization_training_session.rb**

```
class OrganizationTrainingSession
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :organization

  field :session_id  # firebase schedule id 
  field :date_time,  type: DateTime
  field :completed,  type: Boolean, default: false
  field :cancelled,  type: Boolean, default: false
  field :client_ids, type: Array
  field :coach_ids,  type: Array
  field :group_name
  field :recurring_sessions_id

  index({client_id: 1})
  index({session_id: 1})
  index({date_time: 1})
  index({client_ids: 1})
  index({completed: 1})
  index({cancelled: 1})
  index({group_name: 1})
  index({coach_ids: 1})
end
```

When I concatenate the results using +, the result is an array. But, I want a query set so that I can do the pagination in the DB level itself.

```
organization_sessions = OrganizationTrainingSession.where(:client_ids => "58358494767f430fc4154fe8")

coach_sessions = CoachTrainingSession.where(:client_ids => "58358494767f430fc4154fe8")
```

I need a query set which is a union of organization_sessions and coach_sessions.

Any help would be great!

Comment: These really should be in the same collection to begin with. You can actually have documents with different structures in the collection, and Mongoid does support mapping the different classes. Point being that is the only practical solution. There is no such thing as a UNION query with MongoDB, and the only other way to merge result sets is "externally". So putting it all in the same collection gives you the most scalable solution.

Comment: Yes, I understand the solution proposed by you. These models are created by some other person. This system is already developed and there are already a huge set of data in the DB. So, I don't think I can easily revamp the collections. Can you please explain more on "externally"?

Comment: As in return all results to arrays and "combine in code". There just is not a union query option, and I'd say "won't be" but six years ago there were never going to be any joins and not transactions either. Who knew? But there is not a "query" option to do this. It's better to fix the code and have the sort of polymorphic model I'm talking about. Sometimes bad design just needs to be scrapped and start again, and as this breaks a basic rule of "one collection per query" then it should be scrapped.